# Topological spaces determined by generalized metric spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology

At http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Real_Analysis/Metric_Spaces you can find the standard definition of a metric space: a set $X$ given with a function $d:X\times X\to\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies properties 1 through 4. Later on the page it defines open ball and open set, and proves that arbitrary unions and finite intersections of open sets are open. (The page has a few mistakes; in particular, in the second paragraph of the proof, the unions should be intersections.) In other words, the open sets form a topology.

What I find remarkable is that none of properties 1 through 4 are needed for this proof. So consider a set $X$ and an arbitrary function $d:X\times X\to\mathbb{R}$. We can define open balls and open sets using the same definitions, producing a topology on $X$. Such topologies can be very different from those that arise from true metrics; for example, if $d$ is identically 0 we get the indiscrete topology.

Can we prove anything interesting about which topologies can arise this way? In particular, does every finite topology arise this way?

Comment: Careful: if $d$ isn't symmetric then there are two notions of open ball ("left open balls" and "right open balls") so you actually get _two_ topologies. A nice example is the "counterclockwise distance" metric on $S^1$. One of the topologies you get is the "topology of counterclockwise convergence" and the other is the "topology of clockwise convergence." 

Comment: No, something IS used. In general the intersection of two "open balls" is not "open".

Comment: @Anton: You don´t need anything to show that the open sets form a topology. It is just that the open balls might not be open so they are not a base for this topology.

Comment: @Ramiro, I guess you want to use open balls as prebase, but that is not "the same definition".

Comment: @Anton: I´m using the definition of "open" given by the OP´s link: $U$ is open iff for every $x \in U$ there is $r>0$ such that $B(x,r) \subseteq U$. With this definition it is obvious that the open sets form a topology. A different matter is whether sets of the form $B(x,r)$ are open or not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some partial answers to OP´s original question:

1) Any first-countable space (and in particular **any finite topology**) can be obtained in this way.

Let $X$ be first-countable, and for each $x \in X$ fix a local neighborhood base $\{B_n^x:n \in \omega \}$ such that $X=B_0^x$ and $B_{n+1}^x \subseteq B_n^x$. We can now define the (not necessarily symmetric) function $$d(x,y)=\inf \left \{\frac{1}{n+1}:y \in B_n^x \right \}.$$

It is not hard to see that the topology defined by this function (defining balls centered at $x$ as $B(x,\varepsilon):=\{y : d(x,y) < \varepsilon \}$) is the same as the original topology on $X$.

2) One can get non-first-countable topologies.

If we let $X=\{a_{n,m} : n,m \in \omega \} \cup \{b_n :n \in \omega\} \cup \{c\}$ and define $d(b_n,a_{n,m})=d(c,b_n)=\frac{1}{n+1}$, $d(x,x)=0$ and $d(x,y)=1$ otherwise, we obtain Arens´ space which is first-countable at every point except at $c$.

3) Not every topology can be obtained in this way.

If $X=D \cup \{\infty\}$ is the one-point compactification of an uncountable discrete space, then the topology of $X$ cannot come from a "generalized metric". Just note that in this situation the balls $B(\infty,1/n)$ have to be open and hence cofinite; thus their intersection is cocountable and therefore the topology induced by the generilized metric wouldn´t be Hausdorff (but the original topology is).

**Edit:** here is another example for 3), prompted by Marcos´ comment, which is interesting because it shows that the class of spaces that we are looking at is not closed under subspaces:

The Arens-Fort space, which is just the subspace $\{a_{n,m} : n,m \in \omega \} \cup \{c\}$ of the Arens´ space defined in 2), can´t be obtained by this procedure. The reason is that the balls $B(x,\varepsilon)$ would have to be open (this is not hard to see) but then $\{B(c,1/n):n \in \omega\}$ whould be a countable local base at $c$.

Comment: Notice that this Arens' space is slightly different from the one given in Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arens%E2%80%93Fort_space), since in this space the set $\{c\}\cup\{a_{n,m}:n,m\in\omega\}$ is not open.

Comment: @Marcos: The $X$ in my answer is the Arens space (usually denoted by $\mathcal{S}_2$), the one given in Wikipedia is the Arens-Fort space which is a (non-open as you point out) subspace of Arens space. Arens-Fort space is not sequential, while Arens space is sequential but not Frechet.

Answer (score 15):

This isn't an answer to exactly your question, but it has been proved that all topological spaces come from suitably generalized metric spaces. Specifically in '['All Topologies Come From Generalized Metrics](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00029890.1988.11971974)'' by Ralph Kopperman in The American Mathematical Monthly he shows that any topological space can be obtained from a generalized metric space where you weaken the axioms and replace $\mathbb{R}$ by a suitable semi-group with certain properties.

It also was shown in ''[Quantales and continuity spaces](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s000120050018)'' by R. C. Flagg in Algebra Universalis that all topological spaces can be obtained by suitable weakenings of the axioms of a metric space and replacing $\mathbb{R}$ by quantales. This is, to my mind, particularly nice as the resulting generalized objects are essentially just categories enriched in the quantale.

Answer (score 3):

Along the lines of Nate's "answer", it is also true that every topology can be induced by a *quasi-gauge*, i.e. by a family of quasi-pseudo-metrics (pseudo- meaning not necessarily Hausdorff; quasi- meaning not necessarily symmetric).